# Visual Studio 2015 - uwp app changes take effect only when i deploy app first

Tags: visual-studio, win-universal-app

I work on a uwp app with visual studio 2015. Normally I can debug the app by pressing F5. When I did some code changes in the uwp app, I have to right click on the project and select deploy. Then I can debug the app, otherwise my code changes, are not considered in the debugged version. Also the breakpoints will not be affected.

Can someone explain this strange behaviour and how I can avoid it? I would like to debug the uwp app (by pressing F5) without having to deploying it every time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It could because your application is not automatically deployed after the build.
You can check this by using the "configuration manager" from the "build" menu and check that your app is selected to be deployed.

[image: Configuration manager]